# unique constraint grouped by other column

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, unique-constraint, composite-key

I have a table which has a father_id column and a serial_number column,
I want to create a unique constraint on the serial number by the father id.

Meaning rows that have the same father_id can't have the same serial_number, but rows that have a different father_id can have the same serial_number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rephrase the requirement, you want the combination of `father_id` and `serial_number` to be unique. Once the requirement is phrased like that, it's easier to translate to SQL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_unq UNIQUE (father_id, serial_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a compound unique key. Here is one way to do it with a unique index:

```
create unique index myindex on mytable(father_id, serial_number);
```

Or in a `create table` statement, with a unique constraint:

```
create table mytable (
    father_id int,
    serial_number int,
    constraint myconstraint unique (father_id, serial_number)
);
```